# Create plugin with multiple blocks

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, block-editor

I made a plugin using default "todo-list" WordPress provides using `npx @wordpress/create-block todo-list`. Is there a way to convert to work with multiple blocks?

Basically I built "todo-list" as default, then made a new directory `blocks/todo-list` and moved src/build folders into there. Then edited `todo-list.php` register_block_type directory from `/build` to `/blocks/todo-list/build`. Then updated package.json start/build scripts to:

```
"build": "wp-scripts build blocks/todo-list/src/index.js --output-path=blocks/todo-list/build",
"start": "wp-scripts start blocks/todo-list/src/index.js --output-path=blocks/todo-list/build"
```

The file structure would be:

```
- blocks
  - todo-list
    - build
    - src
  - block-2
    - build
    - src
- node_modules
- package-lock.json
- package.json
- readme.txt
- todo-list.php
```

I did `npm run build` and don't see Todo List as a block. I didn't add a block-2 yet, but that would be it. Can this structure work?

Edit: Figured it out and answered below.

Comment: as a sidenote, you don't have to use wp scripts to build your block, any webpack config that builds react and spits out a bundle you can enqueue will do. Just make sure it uses the bundle analyser package from WP so you don't bundle WP scripts that already come with WP in your blocks JS bundle

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to debug why it's not showing? I pointed register_block_type to new build path, and don't see any console errors, but no block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the start/build scripts in `package.json` to this and it works.

```
"build": "wp-scripts build --webpack-src-dir=block/post-type-register/src --output-path=block/post-type-register/build",
"start": "wp-scripts start --webpack-src-dir=block/post-type-register/src --output-path=block/post-type-register/build"
```